# Vector space and Unions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Quick question,
Given K and T are subsets of vector space V.

**If** $V = Sp(K) + Sp(T)$, **Does it mean that** $K \cup T$ is a basis of V?

I proved it that way:

If $V = Sp(K) + Sp(T)$, Then $Sp(K) + Sp(T)$ **spans V**, and also is **linearly independent.**
and $K \cup T$ is the same as $Sp(K) + Sp(T)$ which means because it spans and is linearly independent then $K \cup T$  is a base of V.

Did I prove it right?

Comment: The statement is not correct. The flaws in your argument: first, you know nothing about these sets being linearly independent. Second, $K\cup T$ is not the same as the sum of the spans. The first is a set, the second is a vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if $V$ is a vector space and, say, $K=V$? Or, for a more specific example, suppose that $V$ is the cartesian plane, $K$ the $x$-axis and $T$ the $y$-axis?

It turns out that the best you can do is conclude that $K\cup T$ is a spanning set for $V,$ as it may not be linearly independent (see the above examples). However, your method for showing that it spans $V$ isn't correct. We *can't* say that $K\cup T$ is the same as $\operatorname{Sp}(K)+\operatorname{Sp}(T)$--though we *can* say that $\operatorname{Sp}(K\cup T)=\operatorname{Sp}(K)+\operatorname{Sp}(T),$ as I prove partially below. The only time we can say that $K\cup T=\operatorname{Sp}(K)+\operatorname{Sp}(T)$ is when one of $K,T$ contains the other, and whichever contains the other is a vector subspace of $V$ (not just some subset). That is, $K\cup T=\operatorname{Sp}(K)+\operatorname{Sp}(T)$ if and only if

- $K\subseteq T$ and $T=\operatorname{Sp}(T),$ or
- $T\subseteq K$ and $K=\operatorname{Sp}(K).$

---

To prove that $K\cup T$ spans $V$, you'll want to proceed as follows:

> Take any $\vec v\in V.$ Since $V=\operatorname{Sp}(K)+\operatorname{Sp}(T),$ then there exist $\vec k\in\operatorname{Sp}(K)$ and $\vec t\in\operatorname{Sp}(T)$ such that $\vec v=\vec k+\vec t.$ Since $\vec k\in\operatorname{Sp}(K),$ then there exist scalars $a_1,...,a_m$ and vectors $\vec k_1,...,\vec k_m\in K$ such that $$\vec k=a_1\vec k_1+\cdots+a_m\vec k_m.$$ Similarly, there exist scalars $b_1,...,b_n$ and vectors $\vec t_1,...,\vec t_n\in T$ such that $$\vec t=b_1\vec t_1+\cdots+b_n\vec t_n.$$ Thus, $$\vec v=\vec k+\vec t=a_1\vec k_1+\cdots+a_m\vec k_m+b_1\vec t_1+\cdots+b_n\vec t_n,$$ so since $\vec k_1,...,\vec k_m,\vec t_1,...,\vec t_n\in K\cup T,$ then $\vec v\in\operatorname{Sp}(K\cup T).$

More generally, we can use the above approach to see that $\operatorname{Sp}(K)+\operatorname{Sp}(T)\subseteq\operatorname{Sp}(K\cup T).$ The reverse inclusion is also true (I leave the proof to you), so that  $\operatorname{Sp}(K)+\operatorname{Sp}(T)=\operatorname{Sp}(K\cup T).$

---

As I mention in the comments below, given subsets $K,T$ of a vector space $V,$ $K\cup T$ will be a basis for $V$ *if and only if*

1. $K$ and $T$ are both linearly independent sets,
2. $V=\operatorname{Sp}(K)+\operatorname{Sp}(T),$ and
3. $\operatorname{Sp}(K),\operatorname{Sp}(T)$ share only the zero vector.

As discussed/proved above, assumption 2 is enough to ensure that $K\cup T$ is a spanning set for $V.$ However, both assumptions 1 and 3 are necessary to make it linearly independent.

Comment: if K = V then Sp(K) = V, that what you mean?

Comment: That's certainly true, yes. But is $K\cup T$ a basis for $V$?

Comment: It is, because it spans V?

Comment: Is that all it takes to be a basis?

Comment: Nope, I need to show that they're linearly independent too. but they are , aren't they? I just don't know how to prove it but I do know that their sum spans are unproportinate to one another which means their scalars are equal to zero and aren't linearl dependent. Bit messy.. am I right?

Comment: Well, if $K=V$ and $T\subseteq V,$ then $K\cup T=V.$ Of course $V$ spans itself, but is a vector space $V$ a linearly independent set? (In particular, note that the zero vector is an element of $V.$)

Comment: vector space V isn't because V= 1 * V which makes it linearly dependent. but I still didn't get how to show that intersection of K and T are a basis of V.

Comment: It is a union, not an intersection. And you *can't* show linear independence of $K\cup T$, because it need not be true in general. $K\cup T$ will be a basis for $V$ *if and only if* (i) $K$ and $T$ are both linearly independent sets, (ii) $V=\operatorname{Sp}(K)+\operatorname{Sp}(T),$ and (iii) $\operatorname{Sp}(K),\operatorname{Sp}(T)$ share only the zero vector.

Comment: Thanks so much, unfortunately I fail to show in that high level like you showed, I'm still practicing it, but it does make sense that the union of K and T are a basis of V is their spans equal to V. thx again.

Comment: You are very welcome. I definitely recommend that you practice that sort of proof. (Perhaps you should try to prove some of the results that I mentioned but didn't prove.) All that we're really doing in that proof is applying the definitions of span and sum.